# Animated Pulsating Dot

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to add an animated dot that has an oscillating type animation (this will actually be drawn on top of an image, if that makes any difference).

Here's a sample of what I mean:

[image]

Could this somehow be done with two images and an animation between them? I'm not too clear on that, so some sample code would be nice. (or a link to a tutorial).

Cheers and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about Your exact requirements, but for me it looks like You need smth like extending 'ring' above the circle. I've tried to implement it using custom ViewGroup in order to have all that functionality encapsulated in some 'container'. Steps are below:

1) Add values/attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="OscillatorAnimatedView">
        <attr name="centerImage" format="reference" />
        <attr name="oscillatorImage" format="reference" />
        <attr name="oscillatorInterval" format="integer" />
        <attr name="oscillatorMaxExtend" format="float" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

2) Add view to You layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.alexstarc.tests"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.alexstarc.tests.views.OscillatorAnimatedView
            android:id="@+id/oscillator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            custom:centerImage="@drawable/center"
            custom:oscillatorImage="@drawable/circle" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

3) Add images for center and circle to Your drawables (below is just random examples from the internet, note thayt it should be png with transparency):
[image: drawable/center] drawable/center
[image: drawable/circle] drawable/circle

4) Create Your view (in my case it's `com.alexstarc.tests.views.OscillatorAnimatedView`):

```
    package com.ruinalst.performance.tests.views;

    import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
    import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.res.TypedArray;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.animation.BounceInterpolator;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import com.ruinalst.performance.tests.R;

    /**
     * Specific view to provide 'oscilllator' kind of animation using two input views
     */
    public final class OscillatorAnimatedView extends RelativeLayout {

        /* Internal constants, mostly for default values */
        /** default oscillator interval */
        private static final int DEFAULT_INTERVAL = 700;
        /** default oscillator extend */
        private  static final float DEFAULT_EXTEND = 1.5f;

        /** Image to be displayed at the center */
        private ImageView mCenterImage = null;
        /** Image to oscillate */
        private ImageView mOscillatorImage = null;
        /** Oscillator animation */
        private AnimatorSet mAnimatorSet = null;

        public OscillatorAnimatedView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            initAndCompose(attrs);
        }

        public OscillatorAnimatedView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            initAndCompose(attrs);
        }

        /**
         * Internal init function to init all additional data
         * and compose child for this ViewGroup
         *
         * @param attrs {@link AttributeSet} with data from xml attributes
         */
        private void initAndCompose(final AttributeSet attrs) {

            if (null == attrs) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Attributes should be provided to this view," +
                        " at least centerImage and oscillatorImage should be specified");
            }

            final TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                    R.styleable.OscillatorAnimatedView, 0, 0);
            final Drawable centerDrawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.OscillatorAnimatedView_centerImage);
            final Drawable oscillatorDrawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.OscillatorAnimatedView_oscillatorImage);

            if (null == centerDrawable || null == oscillatorDrawable) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Attributes should be provided to this view," +
                        " at least centerImage and oscillatorImage should be specified");
            }

            final int oscillatorInterval = a.getInt(R.styleable.OscillatorAnimatedView_oscillatorInterval, DEFAULT_INTERVAL);
            final float maxOscillatorExtend = a.getFloat(R.styleable.OscillatorAnimatedView_oscillatorMaxExtend, DEFAULT_EXTEND);

            a.recycle();

            // Create child and add them into this view group
            mCenterImage = new ImageView(getContext());
            mCenterImage.setImageDrawable(centerDrawable);
            addInternalChild(mCenterImage);

            mOscillatorImage = new ImageView(getContext());
            mOscillatorImage.setImageDrawable(oscillatorDrawable);
            addInternalChild(mOscillatorImage);

            // Init animation
            mAnimatorSet = new AnimatorSet();

            mAnimatorSet.setDuration(oscillatorInterval);

            final ObjectAnimator scaleXAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mOscillatorImage, "ScaleX", 1.0f, maxOscillatorExtend);

            scaleXAnimator.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
            scaleXAnimator.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);

            final ObjectAnimator scaleYAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mOscillatorImage, "ScaleY", 1.0f, maxOscillatorExtend);

            scaleYAnimator.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
            scaleYAnimator.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);

            mAnimatorSet.playTogether(scaleXAnimator, scaleYAnimator);
            mAnimatorSet.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
        }

        /**
         * Internal helper to add child view to this ViewGroup.
         * Used currently only for two internal ImageViews
         *
         * @param child {@link ImageView} to be added
         */
        private void addInternalChild(final ImageView child) {
            final LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            params.addRule(CENTER_IN_PARENT, 1);
            addView(child, params);
        }

        /**
         * Starts animation for this view
         */
        public void start() {
            mAnimatorSet.start();
        }

        /**
         * Stops animation for this view
         */
        public void stop() {
            mAnimatorSet.end();
        }
    }
```

5) In Your activity do smth like:

```
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            mOscillatorView.start();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();

            mOscillatorView.stop();
        }
```

Please note, that it's not release version and it most probably can be improved in many ways.

You can also play with [interpolators](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/TimeInterpolator.html) or create Your own in order to have expected animation.

Comment: The class with has problem while  institiate with view

Comment: Which problem is it? Feel free to update it and suggest an edit.

Comment: Have you called start?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a [Drawable Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html)? Seems like that would do what you're looking for. You can use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) to position it on top of your other views.

Also, if you need more complex animation, you could use a [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) and paint the canvas to your linking.

Answer (score 0):

Override the onDraw method and draw a first circle for your button, also, create a boolean variable to control when your button is going to pulse and when is not.Finally draw your second circle with an alpha as a background. Making a pulsating effect:

```
 @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    int w = getMeasuredWidth();
    int h = getMeasuredHeight();
    //Draw circle
    canvas.drawCircle(w/2, h/2, MIN_RADIUS_VALUE , mCirclePaint);        
    if (mAnimationOn) {
        if (mRadius >= MAX_RADIUS_VALUE)
            mPaintGoBack = true;
        else if(mRadius <= MIN_RADIUS_VALUE)
            mPaintGoBack = false;
        //Draw pulsating shadow
        canvas.drawCircle(w / 2, h / 2, mRadius, mBackgroundPaint);
        mRadius = mPaintGoBack ? (mRadius - 0.5f) : (mRadius + 0.5f);
        invalidate();
    }

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
 public void animateButton(boolean animate){
    if (!animate)
        mRadius = MIN_RADIUS_VALUE;
    mAnimationOn = animate;
    invalidate();
}
```